# SQL rows into columns with forming groups

Tags: sql-server

Please help me with this task, I actually spent all day long, trying to solve this problem.

I have this table

| PaintedObjectID | CanOfPaintID | ColorOfCan |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | R |
| 3 | 6 | G |
| 3 | 9 | B |
| 6 | 10 | R |
| 6 | 17 | R |
| 6 | 18 | G |
| 6 | 19 | B |

and need to get this one:

| PaintedObjectID | numberOfGroup | RedCanOfPaintID | GreenCanOfPaintID | BlueCanOfPaintID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 6 | 9 |
| 6 | 1 | 10 | 18 | 19 |
| 6 | 2 | 17 | NULL | NULL |

so  for each PaintedObjectID we need subsequently form first group of RedCan & GreenCan & BlueCan and assign it numberOfGroup =1, if there are more cans spent for that PaintedObjectID, then fill second group (assign numberOfGroup=2), etc.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/20166b/1/0) (without solution, but with filled source table)

Do you have any idea of how this can be done?

Answer (score 3):

First use ROW_NUMBER to generate the `numberOfGroup` then pivot.  eg

```
with q as
(
  select  *, row_number() over ( partition by PaintedObjectId, ColorOfCan order by CanOfPaintId) numberOfGroup
  from [PaintedObject_CanOfPaint]
)
select PaintedObjectID, 
       numberOfGroup, 
       max(case when ColorOfCan = 'R' then CanOfPaintId else null end) RedCanOfPaintId,
       max(case when ColorOfCan = 'G' then CanOfPaintId else null end) GreenCanOfPaintId,
       max(case when ColorOfCan = 'B' then CanOfPaintId else null end) BlueCanOfPaintId
from q
group by PaintedObjectID, numberOfGroup
order by PaintedObjectID, numberOfGroup
```

outputs

```
 PaintedObjectID numberOfGroup        RedCanOfPaintId GreenCanOfPaintId BlueCanOfPaintId
--------------- -------------------- --------------- ----------------- ----------------
3               1                    3               6                 9
5               1                    11              13                15
5               2                    12              14                16
6               1                    10              18                19
6               2                    17              NULL              NULL
```